# Prompt event occurs from eveywhere in the screen when taped

Tags: react-native

I am new in React Native. My problem occurred when prompt the event by clicking  the Image icon. I want the prompt event occur from the image button only. But when i click or tap anywhere in the screen, it opens.What can be done to solve this issue ?  In stylesheet, marginBottom and marginRight also doesn't work, so I use marginTop and marginLeft. What can be done to solve this also ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
Image,
TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

import ToolbarAndroid from 'ToolbarAndroid';
import Prompt from 'react-native-prompt';

class DevForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
       message: '',
       promptVisible: false
    };
}
render() {
return (
  <View style = {styles.container}>
    <ToolbarAndroid style = {styles.toolbar}>
      <Text style = {styles.titleText}> Data Collector </Text>
    </ToolbarAndroid>

    <TouchableHighlight 
      onPress={() => this.setState({ promptVisible: true })}
    >
      <Image 
        source = {require('./icon_container/ic_plus_circle_add_new_form.png')} 
        style = {styles.addButton}       
      />
    </TouchableHighlight>
     <View style = {{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style = {{ fontSize: 20 }}>
          {this.state.message}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <Prompt
        title = "Write title of form "
        placeholder = "Your title is here"
        visible = {this.state.promptVisible}
        onCancel = {() => this.setState({ promptVisible: false, message: 'You cancel it !!!'})}
        onSubmit={(value) => this.setState({ promptVisible: false, message: `You title is "${value}"` })}
      />
  </View>
  );
 }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  toolbar: {
    height: 56,
    backgroundColor: '#3F51B5'
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  addButton: {
    marginLeft: 270,
    marginTop: 420,
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DevForm', () => DevForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

So What I could figure out after running the code is that prompt dialog only appears in the area covered by marginLeft and marginTop not the complete screen if you didn't have marginLeft and marginTop it would have been difficult to reproduce this bug. There might be a bug in the npm library "react-native-prompt" that you are using in this example other than that I am not sure what's actually going wrong.